# Plugin options table,is the data serialized

Tags: plugin-development

I am planning on building a plugin and i need to know if the data stored in the options table i will create for the plugin will be serialized or it will be in the ordinary sql format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on what data is being stored in the option, `maybe_serialize` will determine in the option is holding a singular static value, such as `true/false`, `0/1`, `empty string`, whatever(it's called when an option is created or updated).. it will serialize when dealing with objects and arrays, singular values are not serialized.

The `get_option` function is equipped to deal with this however and will unserialize(or not) as necessary for you(using `maybe_unserialize`) when it's called, which basically does the inverse of `maybe_serialize`.

Hope that helps..

**EDIT:** *Confirmed - checked source, above information is correct regarding serialization.*

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is searilized.

update_option() function serailizes the data passed.

The get_option() function deseralizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on some factors.

If you're storing options in the db trough WP's API, like using [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) then the data is automatically serialized by WP if the option is a array.

(same happens in widgets)

If you don't want serialized data then just don't pass arrays to add_option. If you have multiple options you could serialize it yourself and send it as a string before you pass it to the function...