# How to retrieve the value stored in a multi-dimensional array and SUM the entries?

Tags: customization, database

I'm trying to retrieve multidimensional values stored in `user_meta` where the meta key is `my_posts` and the `meta_value` is :

> a:3:{i:0;s:2:"23";i:1;s:2:"20";i:2;s:1:"9";}

Somewhere in the admin page i want to show the sum of the selected posts which are stored in the value above....

Comment: if by sum you mean amount then you can use echo count(unserialize('a:3:{i:0;s:2:"23";i:1;s:2:"20";i:2;s:1:"9";}
'));

Answer (score 6):

The value is serialized, if you retrieve the meta data with the WordPress functions you'll get that data back unserialized, and you'll be able to iterate over it(looks like an array).

```
$somevar = get_user_meta( '99999', 'your-key', true );
```

As with options in WordPress, user meta is serialized when it's an array or object, single values get stored as a string(unserialized).

Call `get_user_meta` and you will get back an array of data back instead of a serialized string, there's no need for you to serialize and unserialize yourself, the WordPress meta functions take care of this for you, using `maybe_serialize` and `maybe_unserialize` when getting and setting meta.

This is similar to option handling in WP and does pretty much the same thing, i covered this when answering "[Plugin options table,is the data serialized](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/plugin-options-table-is-the-data-serialized/5849#5849)"..

To answer the question more directly though, to total the values in the array use `array_sum`, like so..(based on the example var earlier)

```
if( !empty( $somevar ) )
    $sum = array_sum( $somevar );
```

Or..

```
$sum = 0;
if( !empty( $somevar ) ) {
    foreach( $somevar as $int )
        $sum = $sum + $int;
}
```

Assuming it's a simple array of key => value pairs either approach should work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP solution:

```
$tmp = 'a:3:{i:0;s:2:"23";i:1;s:2:"20";i:2;s:1:"9";}';
echo sum_array(unserialize($tmp));
```

Comment: There's no need to do unserialization with user meta, it's only serialized because the meta data is an array or object(see my answer, which will be posted in just a sec).

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know user_meta was unserialized on the fly since I've never had to use it for now ;)

Comment: I wasn't sure initially, so i checked the source, handy to know WordPress does serialization on user meta to.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also...cast your meta value as an array and look at the `wp_count_posts()` and how it's used in wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php for an example.